# How to get gender in instagram API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am working on Instagram API.In which i want to list of user by its gender.it is possible to get users gender using Instagram API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible according to instagram docs only these things are possible

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
        "bio": "This is my bio",
        "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
        "counts": {
            "media": 1320,
            "follows": 420,
            "followed_by": 3410
        }
}
```